# Command output from Variable showing spaces

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to extract the key for a user but I get unwanted spaces and newlines before the string and after it.  My script is the following:

```
$File = gwmi Win32_UserProfile -co MADS000001 |
        select localpath, sid |
        Where-Object {$_.localpath -eq "C:\Users\Administrator"} |
        select Sid |
        ft -HideTableHeaders |
        Out-String -Stream
Write-Host $file
```

How can I get rid of them?

The output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what your goal/purpose is. Are you wanting to remove stale/obsolete user profiles? (Tell _what_ you want to do, not _how_ you think it needs to be done.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of your goal.

If you want to find out the name of the local Administrator account (even if it's been renamed), you can write this:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter 'LocalAccount=TRUE AND SID LIKE "%-500"' |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

If you want that user's profile path, you can combine them:

```
$adminSID = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter 'LocalAccount=TRUE AND SID LIKE "%-500"' |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty SID
$profilePath = [WMI] "root\cimv2:Win32_UserProfile.SID='$adminSID'" |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty LocalPath
```

Note the use of `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` to select a specific property and output *only* that property.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, not quite my goal, what i want it's find the SID for a user that will be a variable when i get this right, and then delete it. It's for recreating local profiles, deleting the registry entry. So i thought, finding the SID with the profilepath, and then deleting it with the full key path and then the SID that i got with that command. The problem is that i get those annoying spaces before and after the SID...

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΓιοςτουΉρας - See my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over complicating it a bit.
If you just do

```
$profileInfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile -ComputerName 'MADS000001' |
               Where-Object {$_.localpath -like "*\Administrator"} |
               Select-Object LocalPath, Sid, PSComputerName
```

You will get an object (if found of course, `$null` otherwise) with the three properties in the `Select-Object` command.

The `$profileInfo.LocalPath` you can use to delete the folder.
The `$profileInfo.Sid` string value you can use to remove the registry key for that user at
`HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\<SID>`

P.s. The second 'unwanted' whitespace you have outlined is simply a newline Write-Host always adds unless you use `Write-Host $profileInfo.Sid  -NoNewline`

Answer (score 0):

To get the SID for a user:

```
$userName = "Administrator"
$sid = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount=TRUE AND Name='$username'" |
 Select-Object -ExpandProperty SID
```

Note that this will fail if the user is not named `Administrator`.

Also - note the use of `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` to select the value of a specific property of an object.